# Assign the value of ButtonStyle configuration.isPressed to other variable

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have 2 questions, first, I have this code and I'm trying to assign the value of `configuration.isPressed` (in `ButtonStyle` ) to the variable `@State var isPressed`

```
import SwiftUI
import ARKit

struct ContentView: View {
        
    @State var isPressed: Bool = false
       
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                  Text("Hello World")
                }
                .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle(p: $isPressed))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
  @Binding var p: Bool
  func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
      .padding()
      .foregroundColor(.white)
      .background(Color.blue)
      .cornerRadius(8.0)
    
    if configuration.isPressed {
        ////CODE HERE ?
    }
  }
}
```

Is the above possible?

Second questions: I found plenty of ways to detect when a button is pressed and released. Is the usage `ButtonStyle` a good practice/way to achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure... `configuration.isPressed` is a get-only property, so you wouldn't be able to set it. You might be able to make a custom binding though

Comment: Hi @aheze, I'm not trying to assign a value to `configuration.isPressed`, instead, I'm trying to assign the value of it to `@State var isPressed`, I hope it makes more sense now.